# Ignoring an specific element on javascript function

Tags: javascript, xui

I've got this javascript/xuijs function:

```
 function clearListBoxInputs(divelement,selected) {
    x$(divelement).find("input").each(function(element, index, xui) {
        x$(element).filter(function () {
                return this.checked;
            }).each(function (element, index, xui) {
                element.checked = false;
            });
   });
}
```

selected contains this value "input#Q1793_QO5527". divelement contains this value: "div#divQ1793".
element is each element (checkbox) inside "div#divQ1793": "input#Q1793_QO5527", "input#Q1793_QO5528","input#Q1793_QO5529",...
What I want to do is uncheck all input elements inside "div#divQ1793" except the one specified on selected ("input#Q1793_QO5527").
How can I ignore this one?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `.filter()` and `.each()` on a single element? That's generally only needed for collections of multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude a matching element.

```
function clearListBoxInputs(divelement, selected) {
    x$(divelement).find("input:checked").not(selected).prop("checked", false);
}
```

No need for all the `.each` and `.filter` loops, because `.prop()` automatically loops over all the elements.